# Access the value of a variable outside its scope

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and trying to automate a window app using appium .I have the following code

```
int i = -1;

foreach (var row in SummaryTableRows)
{
    i++;
    //Console.WriteLine(row.Text);
    if ((row.Text.Contains("cheq")) && (row.Text.Contains("acitve")))
    {
        var DemandData = FirstRow.Split(new[] { " " }, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        string Sub = DemandData[1];
        string Type = DemandData[0];
        bFlag = true;
        break;
    }
}

buttonBar.ExitFormBtn.Click();
buttonBar = null;
//Should be back to member form
SubCheq.SendKeys(Sub + Keys.Tab);
```

I want to access the value of Sub and Type outside the if loop. In vb script it was never an issue but seems like in C# the scope of the variable is limited to the foreach block. So My question how can I access the value of Sub and Type.

Comment: Just move the definition of the variables to the scope where you need it.

Comment: In order to accomplish your goal, you must declare your two variables BEFORE the loop. Then, you can set them in your loop and use them outside the scope of the loop.

Comment: As others have pointed out, you need to put the variable declarations outside the loop. But the better solution would be to *not write a loop in the first place*. instead write `bool bFlag = SummaryTableRows.Any(row => row.Text.Contains... );` No loop, no loop body, no variable declaration problem!

Comment: Also, I note that Hungarian conventions are not commonly used in C#; instead of `bFlag`, make your variable have a meaningful name like `containsMatch`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access a variable outside of it's scope. The scope literally means "where you can access the variable". So you want to accesss the values, where you can not access the values. At wich point you can access the variable there, and that is it's new [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).

What you can do is change the scope. If you want a variable avalible outside a specific block, declare it outside of that block. Just declare sub (and propably type) outside the loop. Then only set the values insdie it, with every loop.

I am unsure why you even ask, as you **already do that** with `i`: `int i = -1;` is a declaration with initialisation. And `i++;` is jsut shorthad for `i=i+1;`, so you re-assing it every loop (the new value just happens to be close to the ol one). Strings you many want to initialize with null or maybe a empty string, depending on what you do with it later/how you check for 0 itterations of the foreach loop.

Comment: Let's be precise. "Scope" in C# means *the region of program text in which the element can be accessed by its unqualified name*.  If we have `class C { static public int x; void M() { int y = x;  } class D { void M() { int y = C.x; } }` then the variable `C.x` is not *in scope* inside `D.M` but you can still *access* it.  You cannot access it *by the name `x`*, like you can in `C.M`. Inside `C.M`, `C.x` is *in scope* so it can be accessed by `x`.

Comment: @EricLippert Good point. However in your example `C` would be the important element that needs to be in scope. And it is in scope, because it is defined in the same Namespace, the same file or made visible via a using. `C` jsut brings along it's public static members.

Comment: That's correct. *The scope of the name of a class in a namespace is the body of the namespace*. My point is that your statement "scope means where you can access a variable" is going in the right direction but not quite there. As you note, "C" has a scope but **C is not a variable**.

Comment: Also as you note, C "brings along" its public static members, but the way we resolve that is actually a bit more complex. C brings along *all* its members, static or instance, public or private, inherited or declared. Member resolution then considers not the *scope* of the members -- since that is not relevant -- but rather the *accessibility domain* of those members and whether or not the current location is in that domain. This is one of the more complicated parts of the specification, so if the subject interests you, I encourage you to dive in!